# Any way to change the color of a bar inside of a table?

Tags: css

I am trying to change the color of the bar below `Student`, `Question`, and `Activity`. It seems that I can't inspect the element directly, so I am really not sure how I would go about changing the color.

[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-sort-order="posters" class="posters">Student</th>
    <th data-sort-order="default" class="default">
      <button class="btn-flat bulk-select" title="toggle bulk selection of topics">
        <svg class="fa d-icon d-icon-list svg-icon svg-string" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <use xlink:href="#list"></use>
        </svg>
      </button>
      Question
    </th>
    <th data-sort-order="activity" class="activity sortable num">Activity</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: It's likely not a separate element, but the border of some element. E.g. `<tr>` or `<thead>`

Comment: Right, I thought that. I tried to change the border color of `<thead>`, but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Could also be the following `<tbody>` or `<tr>`

Comment: @weirdan You were right... Top of <tbody>. Should I close my question? What should I do?

Comment: Questions on SO don't need to be closed. You don't need to do anything.